# Recycler View double items on change fragment

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with the recyclerview in my app i have 2 fragments in the first one there is the recycler view which has to find the songs present in the device and put them in line in the second for now nothing. when I switch from one fragment to another the recycler view items double each time.
CODE:

HomeActvity

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    TextView noMusicTextView;
 
    HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    ProvaFragment provaFragment = new ProvaFragment();
 
 
    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
 
 
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
 
        noMusicTextView = findViewById(R.id.noSongs);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.barra_navigazione);
 
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenitore_frammenti, homeFragment).commit();
 
        bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.home:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenitore_frammenti, homeFragment).commit();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.prova:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenitore_frammenti, provaFragment).commit();
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
 
 
 
 
    }
 
 
}
```

HomeFragment

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
 
    ArrayList<AudioModel> songsList = new ArrayList<>();
 
 
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    TextView noMusicTextView;
 
    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
 
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        noMusicTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.noSongs);
 
        String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
 
        };
 
 
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " !=0";
 
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,projection,selection,null,null);
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            AudioModel songData = new AudioModel(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(2));
            if(new File(songData.getPath()).exists())
                songsList.add(songData);
 
        }
 
        if(songsList.size() == 0){
            noMusicTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new MusicListAdapter(songsList, getContext()));
 
        }
 
 
        return view;
    }
 
}
```

MusicListAdapter

```
public class MusicListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MusicListAdapter.ViewHolder>{
 
    ArrayList<AudioModel> songsList;
    Context context;
 
 
    public MusicListAdapter(ArrayList<AudioModel> songsList, Context context) {
        this.songsList = songsList;
        this.context = context;
    }
 
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item,parent,false);
        return new MusicListAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
 
    }
 
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        AudioModel songData = songsList.get(position);
        holder.titleTextView.setText(songData.getTitle());
 
    }
 
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return songsList.size();
    }
 
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
 
        TextView titleTextView;
        ImageView iconImageView;
 
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            titleTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.music_title_text);
            iconImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_view);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tryed to use songsList.clear(); but this don't work(Sorry for my english).

Answer (score 0):

When switching fragments, existing fragments aren't deleted.
Also, songsList isn't initialized; `onViewCreated()` is called at this time, so it seems that the transition adds the item to the `songsList`.
In order to solve the problem, it seems that it is necessary to do a good comparison so that the same item as the previously saved item is not added, or to not add an item every time in onViewCreated.